# convert byte array to image / parameter is not valid error in c#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I want to change byte array to image file.
But I am getting error

> Prameter is not valid.

input data

```
type : byte[]
byte array length : 996
byte order : little endian
```

It is assumed that there are no errors in the input data.

What I've tried:

ImageConverter , MemoryStream

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
 System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms,false,false);
```

i need help.....

result of Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

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

Comment: "It is assumed that there are no errors in the input data" - that seems like a dubious assumption to make, given the result. What's *in* the byte array? `Image.FromStream` expects an image encoded as a PNG or JPEG or similar. What is the *actual* content of the byte array?

Comment: "i need help..... extra, can I make an image with an int array?" - Please ask one question per post.

Comment: The byte array contains 255 or fewer numbers.
And I am in a position where there is no doubt about INPUT DATA. This is because I received it as a job assignment.
However, to infer the data I received, these are the data that cut one image horizontally.
And I'll separate the questions. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: You should start with an `Image` and create a `byte` array, then try to create an `Image` from that using the same code. Does it work? If so then you know the code is OK and it's the data that is the issue.

Comment: "The byte array contains 255 or fewer numbers" - that really doesn't say anything about what they mean. For a start: what determines the size of the image? If it's a "simple" image format, how many bytes per pixel, and in what format? If you don't have that information, and it's not in a well-known image format (like JPG or PNG) then there's no way of constructing an image.

Comment: When you want to convert it to image, do you mean you want it displayed somewhere, or do you want an Image file to be created in some folder?

Comment: And you claim that "The byte array contains 255 or fewer numbers" - but your array is 996 elements. So how many bytes per "number" here? There's just *so* much information that either you haven't been given, or you haven't given to us.

Comment: Can you copy the result of `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);` here?

Comment: I thought it would be a simple problem, so I didn't deliver all the information I knew
First of all, I'm using a translator, so I think my words were misrepresented.
Because it's a byte array, of course, I wanted to say that the elements in it contain numbers less than 255.

I have information that it is an image that can be converted into png in the future, and that the image data is composed of an integrator unit.

Comment: However, as a result of the search, I didn't see the code that processes the byte array by 4 bytes, so I was also curious if I could create an image with an int array.

And within the bite array, there was information about the length of the image data and the order of the split images.
From that, I was able to know the length of the image data.

I'm not sure what I'm saying
But thank you for continuing to be interested and curious

Comment: Your byte array only contains 0 and 0xff, that's definitely not a valid jpg or png file. Don't you know the format?

Comment: Where DO you get the Image data from? What kind of programm is this going to be?

Comment: Is it in the realm of possibilities that they are testing you if you dare to ask questions about what you have been given to work with? If you just take it as a given that the input data is what it is claimed to be (and you seem to know not very much about it) and it turns out, it's not - then all your effort (and paid work hours) has been futile and wasted.

Comment: It is the data received as required to use that data.

There were a total of 60 data, and I just checked and found that there was a slight difference in order, but all of them consisted of 0 and 255

I didn't know about the plain byte format because it was my first time trying to deal with the byte array..

Can't I use 4byte by tying it up and using it in an int format? so sad..

Comment: Well no you cant use a int array for this

Comment: But still from where do you get the data? do you just tell your programm a folder path from which it is to take all exiting images?

Comment: Where do you get your error message? Like at what point is it thrown? In general it would be very helpfull if you could show us the full method/function you are using

Comment: Then you have to know the width or height, note 996 = 12 * 83, 83 is a prime, so whatever it is 3 or 4 byte per pixel, it's an image like a stick which is weired.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to represent a image as a byte array:

#### An image file

This contains data that are somehow encoded. It is common for file data to be prefixed by a [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). A Jpeg should start with `FF D8 FF` as an example. Image files should contain all necessary metadata, and should be loaded as in your example.

#### Raw data

This means the data array contains raw pixel values. Unfortunately this is not sufficient to reconstruct the image. You also need to know at least:

1. image width (number of pixels on a row)
2. Pixel format
3. Image stride ( number of bytes on a row)

You may be able to guess some of these parameters, stride and width are often related for example.

Based on your data, and the fact that you get an error, my guess would be that you have raw pixel values. So you need to get the other information somehow. Once you have that data you can create a bitmap, use [LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) to gain access to the pixel buffer, and use one of the [memory copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.memorycopy?view=net-8.0) functions to copy pixels over.

You could perhaps *guess* the image parameters. I.e. assume it is is RGB, so 3 bytes per pixels, giving 332 pixels total, i.e. ~18x18 ?